Automatically retrieve booster role using discord.js v13
I wanted to ask if there is any possibility to write an event code that will retrieve (get) the booster role of each server the bot is on, and write in the json.sqlite database I'm using with my bot script.
To be more precise, the database system I'm using is the quick.db module, so yeah, what I would do is basically fetch the booster role by using any method, and store it in the sqlite db I got using the quick.db module (as every command and shit does in my code)
I'll be glad for your help, your advices will be rlly helpful to me ! :D

Hi Wayz, welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried first before asking here? Have you read the documentation for the APIs you're working with?

You can obtain the Premium Subscriber role (or Booster role) throught the RoleManager of the guild.
In this example, myGuild represents the guild you are querying as an object of type Guild.
let boosterRole = myGuild.roles.premiumSubscriberRole;

Refer to the RoleManager documentation for further details.
Sidenote, do consider updating to discord.js v14 when possible.
